# Pandas Group Counting Frequency of NaT and Datevalues by month, week, day in the same colum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

#### So here is some biz logic to understand the problem:

In ['Stuffed'] there are dates, and NaT/(blanks).

- if row has date = container is stuffed
- if row is blank = container is not stuffed

I was able to get the Stuffed Containers per /month /week, /day 
but Not the blanks!

Im trying to create a status of stuffed vs unstuffed /month , /week, /day

Any ideas?

```
# Containers database has multiple entries of the same ID so .nunique() is required to filter 

stuff_cont = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Stuffed', freq='M')])['Container'].nunique() 

stuff_cont.head(10)


Stuffed
2019-01-31    179
2019-02-28    287
2019-03-31    462
2019-04-30    588
2019-05-31    587
2019-06-30    530
2019-07-31    317
2019-08-31    237
2019-09-30    163
2019-10-31    283
Name: Container, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `pd.concat([stuff_cont, df.loc[df['Stuffed'].isna(), 'Container']])` ?

Comment: I justa added : `df.loc[df['Estufagem'].isna(), 'Container'].count()`
here is the output:

And it works giving me exact number of blanks. 
Hahaha easier then what I thought. Thank you @ScottBoston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([stuff_cont, df.loc[df['Stuffed'].isna(), 'Container'].count()])
```

This will combine the results with groupby and a count all all the NaN 'Stuffed' records.